# Minecaft Fabric 1.19.3 EventListening when Player joins Server (Client)

Tags: java, event-handling, minecraft, packet, minecraft-fabric

I am trying to find a packet or a method to listen to when a player joins the server your in.

I didn't find any packet or class the nearest think I found was the spawn player packet but this happens when a player enters view distance.

Comment: It seems to be like `EntityJoinWorldEvent` does it already exists ?

Comment: I found a Player Info Update packet that updates tab but i dont know how to listen to it

Comment: Oh yes, it can help. You should use `player.networkHandler.connection.getChannel().pipeline()` then use addBefore or addAfter. The `getChannel()` can doesn't exist, if it doesn't: use reflection

Comment: can you please explain it more detailed?

Comment: i cand seem to find the getChannel method are you sure its in fabric?

Comment: i now used reflextion but there is still no add before or addafter method

Comment: I'll make an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is multiple ways.

1. Use the `EntityJoinWorldEvent`. Multiple post were talking about this one, not sure it's fully working and can't find documentation about it.
2. Listen for join message as "XX joined the game", this can be used only if it's for specific servers
3. Use packet. As you said, the PlayerInfoPacket can answer. To get it, you can you (at join of server for example) :

   ```
   try {
        Channel channel = ReflectionUtils.getFirstWith(player.networkHandler.connection, ClientConnection.class, Channel.class);
        if(channel == null) {
            getLogger().warn("Failed to load packet");
        } else {
            // Managing incoming packet
            channel.pipeline().addBefore("packet_handler", "packet_handler" + p.getName(), new ChannelHandlerReceive(p));
        }
   } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

The `"packet_handler"` is a specific key, but the `"packet_handler" + p.getName()` can be replaced by what you want, it only will name your own listener.

For the `ReflectionUtils.getFirstWith()`, you can check [here](https://github.com/Elikill58/Negativity/blob/v2/common/src/com/elikill58/negativity/universal/utils/ReflectionUtils.java#L68-L76) for the code.

Then, add this class that will be able to read packets :

```
private class ChannelHandlerReceive extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private final Player owner;

    public ChannelHandlerReceive(Player player) {
        this.owner = player;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object packet) throws Exception {
        // here check what is packet, and if it's the PlayerInfoPacket -> that's it !
        super.channelRead(ctx, packet); // don't forget this line !!
    }
}
```

For the full code I'm using, you can check [here](https://github.com/Elikill58/Negativity/blob/712245d1777df3550a575fb328db4e5f7cee8ce0/fabric/src/com/elikill58/negativity/fabric/packets/CustomPacketManager.java#L47)

PS: Once you have the packet, don't forget to check for the action (remove player, add player, update name etc)

Comment: thanks you are really helping me out i am trying it out now